# Problem loading optidef package and addtocontents

Tags: optidef

I am using Miktex 2.9 with Texstudio 2.12.6. My document is in `KOMA`-class. As I was trying to load the `optidef` package, I got an error which seems related to `\addcontentsline{toc}`.
I assumed some outdated packages to be the cause, so I have updated all packages using Miktex Updater. The problem remains.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN PACKAGES
%%% Page header
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=off]{scrlayer-scrpage}  

%%% Mathematic equations
%\usepackage{optidef}           

 %%% links in pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}        
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END PACKAGES 

\begin{document}

%%% ToC
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\phantomsection                     
\pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{toc}   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents

%%%% from here on: add elements to ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} 

%%%% chapters
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\chapter{Test}
test 

%%%% Optidef Example
%\begin{mini}[2]
%   {w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
%   {\label{eq:Example1}}
%   {}
%   \addConstraint{g(w)}{=0}
%   \addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6}
%   \addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
%   \addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
%\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

Without `optidef` package, the document compiles flawlessly. As soon as I load the package `optidef`, I will get the following error message for all corresponding lines of code:

> Undefined control sequence.
>   \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Dan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some `\protect`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN PACKAGES
%%% Page header
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=off]{scrlayer-scrpage}  

%%% Mathematic equations
\usepackage{optidef}           

 %%% links in pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}        
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END PACKAGES 

\begin{document}

%%% ToC
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\phantomsection                     
\pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{toc}   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents

%%%% from here on: add elements to ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} 

%%%% chapters
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}

\chapter{Test}
test 

%%%% Optidef Example
\begin{mini}[2]
  {w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
  {\label{eq:Example1}}
  {}
  \addConstraint{g(w)}{=0}
  \addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6}
  \addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
  \addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

---

Explanation: `optidef` requires package `calc` and the latter modifies `\setcounter` in a way which makes the `\protect` here needed.

Comment: but these lines do not make much sense anyhow especially one after the other

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Indeed, these lines do not make any sense in the MWE. In my actual document, I am loading prefix chapters in between these lines, which does give them a real purpose :)

Comment: @dan Actually `\protect` should also be used without loading `optidef`.